# Quisiera saber si mi código de lista enlazada es correcto

Tags: c, lista, revisión-de-código, ordenamiento

He realizado un ejercicio de una lista enlazada ordenada y me gustaría que le echarais un vistazo a ver que os parece, si se podría mejorar o algo. El código funciona.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo{
    int dato;
    struct nodo *siguiente;
}Nodo;

Nodo *principio = NULL;
Nodo *final = NULL;

//Prototipos de funciones
void meterLista();
int introducirDatos();
void ordenarLista();
void visualizarLista();

int main()
{
    printf("LISTA ENLAZADA ORDENADA EN C\n");
    printf("Ingrese datos hasta introducir un 0\n\n");
    meterLista();
    printf("\nDatos en la lista enlazada\n");
    visualizarLista();
    printf("\n\nDatos ordenados\n");
    ordenarLista();
    visualizarLista();

    return 0;
}

void meterLista()
{
    Nodo *nuevo;
    int numero = introducirDatos();

    while(numero!=0)
    {
        nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
        nuevo->dato = numero;
        if(principio == NULL)
        {
            principio = nuevo;
            nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
            final = nuevo;
        }
        else
        {
            final->siguiente = nuevo;
            nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
            final = nuevo;
        }
        numero = introducirDatos();
    }
}

int introducirDatos()
{
    int x;
    printf("Dato: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    return x;
}

void ordenarLista()
{
    Nodo *pivote = principio;

    while(pivote!=NULL)
    {
        Nodo *auxiliar = pivote;

        while(auxiliar!=NULL)
        {
            if(pivote->dato > auxiliar->dato)
            {
                int temporal = pivote->dato;
                pivote->dato = auxiliar->dato;
                auxiliar->dato = temporal;  
            }
            auxiliar = auxiliar->siguiente; 
        }
        pivote = pivote->siguiente;
    }
}

void visualizarLista()
{
    Nodo *actual = principio;

    if(actual==NULL)
    {
        printf("  La lista enlazada esta vacia");
    }
    else
    {
        while(actual!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ",actual->dato);
            actual = actual->siguiente;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mis comentarios al respecto:

**¿Variables globales? no, gracias**

```
Nodo *principio = NULL;
Nodo *final = NULL;
```

Las variables globales no son para nada necesarias en este código. Complican el mantenimiento, el depurado y dificultan la portabilidad y la escalabilidad del código... y no hablar ya de entornos multihilo.

**validación de las entradas**

```
int introducirDatos()
{
    int x;
    printf("Dato: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    return x;
}
```

¿Qué sucede si me equivoco y meto una letra en vez de un número? el programa se volverá loco y tendré que cerrarlo, perdiendo todos los cambios, y empezar de cero.

**Siempre** hay que validar las entradas del usuario. La única excepción son los juegos de programación.

```
int introducirDatos()
{
    int x;
    printf("Dato: ");
    if( scanf("%d",&x) != 1 )
    {
      // Se limpia el buffer hasta el salto de linea
      while( getchar() != '\n' ); 
    }
    return x;
}
```

**inicialización de estructuras**

Reservas la memoria con `malloc` y luego tienes que acordarte de inicializar manualmente los punteros del elemento.

Si en alguna edición posterior el código se *olvida* de inicializar el puntero vas a tener comportamientos erráticos.

Esta problemática es tan sencilla de solucionar como usar `calloc` en vez de `malloc`:

```
nuevo = (Nodo*)calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
// en este punto, nuevo->siguiente == NULL
```

**Indica que las funciones no reciben parámetros**

En C, una función tal que:

```
void func();
```

está indicando que admite un número indeterminado de parámetros, mientras que esta otra versión:

```
void func(void);
```

ya está indicando que no acepta absolutamente ninguno. Si omites `void` puedes acabar obteniendo aberraciones como esta:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f()
{
  puts("test");   
}

int main()
{
  f(1,2);
  return 0;
}
```

**Acoplamiento excesivo**

No hay una separación entre la librería que gestiona la lista enlazada y el programa que la usa.

No es trivial sustituir la entrada para que pase a usar un fichero en vez de la entrada estándar... y lo mismo para la salida. Si no aislas el código convenientemente y mezclas las capas de código luego te resultará más complicado o incluso imposible reutilizar las funciones.

Y lo mismo sucede con la ordenación... es imposible cambiar el criterio de ordenación sin modificar la función.

Por poner un ejemplo, para la ordenación podría usarse un esquema como el siguiente:

```
// alias de puntero a función
typedef funcOrdenarLista int(*)(int,int);

// Ordena la lista en base al criterio establecido en una función
// pasada como parámetro
void ordenarLista(Nodo* inicioLista, funcOrdenarLista  funcion);

// Función que indica si el primer valor es mayor que el segundo
int esMayor(int valor1, int valor2);

// ...
ordenarLista(inicioLista,esMayor);
```

Posible implementación:

```
void ordenarLista(Nodo* inicioLista, funcOrdenarLista  funcion)
{
    Nodo *pivote = inicioLista;

    while(pivote!=NULL)
    {
        Nodo *auxiliar = pivote;

        while(auxiliar!=NULL)
        {
            if( (*funcion)(pivote->dato,auxiliar->dato))
            {
                int temporal = pivote->dato;
                pivote->dato = auxiliar->dato;
                auxiliar->dato = temporal;  
            }
            auxiliar = auxiliar->siguiente; 
        }
        pivote = pivote->siguiente;
    }
}
```

**Evita escribir valores en el código**

```
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

¿Y si da la casualidad que el código se compila y ejecuta en una arquitectura en la que el valor 0 indica un error?

En `cstdlib` tienes unas macros muy bonitas para evitar escribir valores en el código:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Y lo mismo es equivalente para números mágicos y otros valores que puedan encontrarse en el código (no es tu caso, pero aprovecho la ocasión).

Usar `#define` para estos casos suele ser beneficioso porque evita tener que recorrer el código cada vez que haya que modificar uno de estos valores (con las consecuentes probabilidades de meter la pata). Modificando el `#define` se actualizan todos los valores en la siguiente compilación.

Comment: Increíble respuesta, me viene de perla, muchas gracias amigo !!